# Image Preloader via JSON, JQUERY, PHP

Tags: php, jquery, json

im attempting to make a auto preloader via php an JSON my reason being no other preloaders suit my purposes at this time. Im developing off a WAMP installation with php version 5.3.0 an apache version 2.2.11 an using the following php code:

```
$rootDir =  dirname(__FILE__).'/..';
$imgdir = opendir($rootDir.'/images/');
$i=0;

while ($file = readdir($imgdir))
{
if (($file != '.') && ($file != '..'))
{
$fileList[$i] = $file;
$i++;
}
}

$json=json_encode($fileList, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
die($json);
```

My Jquery is inline/embeded at the moment (version 1.4.2) and is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "preload/reader.php",
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function(data){
            alert(data);
        }
    });
});
```

this has the following output in an alert box; {"0":"BlueHills.jpg","1":"deagle_descr.jpg","2":"mod.jpg"}

the problem actually starts when i want to do anything else with data, the page never finishes loading like it's stuck in an infinite loop or something. Even just a simple statement like document.write(data); it the page is stuck in loading state until i hit stop in the browser. Im fairly new to JSON please help

Comment: if you are new to JSON/AJAX, you may want to check out `getJSON()` http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Comment: also, try posting a snippet of what you are trying to do with the data.

Answer (score 0):

1. use getJSON
2. in the callback function of getJSON, start adding  tags to the DOM, but hidden by default
3. show then new images whenever you need

Comment: i replaced the above ajax with

$.getJSON("preload/reader.php", function(data){
  $.each(data, function(i,current){
 document.write(current + "<br />");
  });
});

but this still doesnt solve my problem that in firefox the page refuses to finish loading until i hit stop in the browser

Comment: The page not finishing to load might be from somewhere else. Check all the requests that are being made in Firebug's Console.

Comment: by checking in firebug i assume u mean opening the net tab an see all the requests. Well ur outta luck it shows absolutely nothing i know it's working cuz cuz i ran firebug on WAMP's localhost page an it all popped up.
For ina's benefit: Im trying to encode a php array to a JSON Object pass it to JQuery parse the results into a Javascript Array, loop through the javascript array an preload all the images.

Comment: The only thing i can be sure of is it has something to do with AJAX an XHR as if i remove all actions after after the JSON object has been loaded the script loads an everything works fine.

Comment: No, I literary mean Firebug's Console. The 1st tab. Here's a screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/FTto1.png. It shows all the AJAX calls made and you'll see when they finish. 

ina requested a code snippet, not an explanation.

Comment: I am not here to run error checking for u, i am here because i have tried everything i know and still cant solve this dilema. Maybe i wasn't clear enough before, absolutely nothing happens in Firebug console tabs or other wise. And don't tell me to reinstall it cuz i know it works fine already it's on a clean profile with nothing else on there. I'm getting frustrated here please i need a solution not advice on error checking methodologies. Oh an im back to using my original code that i posted here since .getJSON is just an abbreviated form of it.

Comment: Check your attitude. The code you pasted above seems ok, but the lack for AJAX request in the Console is a sign. Paste the code you're running when the browser doesn't stop loading. You mention the alert() is ok, so it's something else.

Comment: I apologize i was frustrated so i took some time off and did some other work for a client in joomla, now im back on the case. I have uploaded screen captures to photobucket album of the firebug console when using an alert:

http://s856.photobucket.com/albums/ab126/Ve9a/Errors/

I shall endeavor to soon make a video using camstudio to show u exactly what happens when i try doing something else with the code